# vb.net Code works locally but not on web server

Tags: mysql, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I've an interesting problem. One of my database related code works good on local machine. But it doesn't return anything from when published on the third party web server.

Following is the code snippet :

```
Public Function getUserAuthDataWithUserId(ByRef Connection As MySqlConnection,
                                              ByVal UserId As String
                                             ) As DataTable

    Dim cmd As String
    cmd = "select * from tbl_md_userauth where tf_userid = '" + UserId + "' "
    getUserAuthDataWithUserId = ExecuteSQL(Connection, cmd)
End Function
```

And the `ExecuteSQL` function is :

```
Public Function ExecuteSQL(ByRef Connection As MySqlConnection,
                               ByVal SQLStatement As String
                                ) As DataTable
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter

    Try
        da = New MySqlDataAdapter(SQLStatement, Connection)
        da.Fill(ds, "tbl_Return")
        ExecuteSQL = ds.Tables("tbl_Return")

    Catch ex As Exception
        msgbox ("exception !")
    End Try
End Function
```

Be assured that :

1. The database table has correct data. And the code works correctly when connecting from local machine to remote desktop.
2. The code works correctly when using local IIS and local database.
3. I've also tried republishing the code twice or thrice.

Helpdesk of web server says there is no problem with their server.

Any clue on what is wrong ?

Comment: Did you change the connection string when publishing to the web server? It might not be the same as on your local machine.

Comment: Are you receiving an exception? What does your catch block return?

Comment: check if you are getting the userId as expected. Are you using anonymous authentication?

Comment: Is it a windows server with the .net framework installed?

Comment: Are you really using a msgbox on the server? That won't show to the clients. You need some other way of messaging the error or logging it.

Comment: You're open for sql-injection, use sql-parameters instead of string concatenation. **Don't "reuse" the connection and in no case make it `Shared` in ASP.NET**.  Also, get familiar with the [`Return`-statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e34641s.aspx) ;-)

Comment: Thanks for replies guys.
1. Catch block does not return anything. Server just keeps on processing (in sort of infinite block)
2. I log the error. I do not use msgbox(). I replaced the original code with msgbox() just to post the question here in order to have a simple code.
3. The connection string is correct. I received it from the hosting solution provider.
4. Yes, it is the Windows server with .net framework installed. Interestingly, it worked earlier. And without publishing the new code, it suddenly stopped working.

Comment: @Sukhi: you haven't answered whether you're connection is `Shared` or not. Use the `Using` statement to always dispose/close the connection as soon as possible with enabled connection-pooling(default).

Comment: No, the connecion is not shared. However, as soon as I do the database operation, I close the connection [from the class where I call getUserAuthDataWithUserId() ].

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you are swallowing your exceptions. The code appears to use a msgbox to display the error, but that will appear on the server under a hidden profile and not be sent to the browser for display. You need some other way of displaying or logging the error that works in a web environment.

That being said, are you able to get any connections to the database and just this method is failing, or are all of your database requests failing? I suspect that you are using integrated authentication in your database configuration, but the same user doesn't work on the server because IIS is running as a different user in the app pool. Try changing your development environment to point to your database on the server and see if you get any errors that way. If you are using a hosting environment, I recommend setting up a named user in your database and using that in your connection string rather than using integrated authentication.

Comment: Cheers Jim.
1. I used msgbox() only to post the question over here. It wasn't in my real code. 
2. I use connection string (and not integrated authentication)
3. Yes, I tried running the code from local machine by pointing the database at remote server. It works good.

Comment: In the connection string, are you specifying the username? Are you getting any error from your catch block? You may also want to check to see if you have error trapping around opening your connection.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, it found to be a server side problem. The Helpdesk fixed it. I am yet to know what precisely they have fixed. I'll problably post it over here as soon as I hear from them.

Thanks to all of you guys who've contributed.